# Deferred.done callback not working in the done function

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to make this work for couple of days now, my last attempt.

And my apologies for posting different questions with similar objective.

I just tried to figure it out with the best way.

Here is the thing; I have some data in another page that I want to use in my initialize function.

One member here suggested that I use deferred.done.

It partially worked. My data in other page is loaded and I can get it displayed if I have **alert(MapData);** in the initialize function.

BUT when I try to use that data in the initialize function for the actual work, I get **MapData.users is undefined** error.

I dont get it because it appears fine when I loaded in an alert box.

Please suggest!

```
    $(function CheckinMap() {
        $.when($.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content/home/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewCheckinMap"
        })).done(      function initialize(data) {
            var MapData = data;
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.404840395764175, 2.6845264434814453);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('checkinmap'), {
              zoom: 2,
              center: center,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              maxZoom: 4
            });
            var markers = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < MapData.users.length; i++) {
              var location = MapData.users[i];
              var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,
                  location.longitude);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng
              });
              markers.push(marker);
            }
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        });
    });
```

This is the data that I need to use in my initialize function.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "latitude": "48.405163",
      "longitude": "2.684659"
    },
    {
      "latitude": "43.7347242529278",
      "longitude": "7.42198348045349"
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap your `$.ajax()` call in a `$.when()` call, it already returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()` call; this likely results in your `data` being the raw text JSON response, and not the decoded object.

Comment: I actually tried this before and the result was same. Therefore I removed it.